# Maximum difference from nearest neighbour

Tags: python, algorithm

I am writing a seat allocation program and focused the problem to a single row of seats. I want to allocate the next seat such that it has the furthest distance from the nearest taken seat. I decided that the problem could be written as follows:
Given a integer list (of all seats) and a subset (of taken seats), find the smallest integer that has the maximum difference from the nearest neighboring number.

For example:

```
Input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,10]
Output: 5
(Actually it is 5 or 6 but we take the smallest)
Input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [5,10]
Output: 1
(1 is 4 numbers away from 5, any other number is 3 or less numbers away from 5 or 10)
Input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,5,10]
Output: 3
(Possible candidates are 3, 7 or 8 but we take the smallest)
```

I have tried to loop each remaining integer through the taken subset and take the average and the sum of differences but the output is not correct.
I am sure there is already an algorithm for this problem. Which algorithm would you use (so that I set myself on the correct direction)? Thank you.

Comment: Is the first parameter ("list of all seats") relevant? Will it ever be sth else than `[1 .. n]`?

Comment: can you explain more about second list for example `[1,5,10]` in the last example ?

Comment: Is the first array always a 1,...,x? or can it also be [1,2,5,10]?

Comment: There are two base cases: either the free region is unbounded (no taken seats) - then you should take the boundary seats to leave the maximum free space, or it is bounded from at least one side. In this case you should consider all sequences between two closest taken seats and the two sequences between the bounds and the seats closest to them. The length of the former minus one divided by two gives you the distance between neighbours while with the latter you only subtract one. You pick the maxima of these and then the leftmost of the ones left.

Comment: You meant "find the smallest integer that has the maximum difference from the nearest _taken_ number", right?

Comment: @martineau Right, nearest taken number! And first input is always [1 .. n]

Comment: @KasraAD In the last example, 3, 7, and 8 are 2 numbers away from 1, 5, and 10 respectively. So we take 3 because it is the smallest. Other numbers are 1 number away from 1, 5 or 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have seats from 1 to n. Notice that the answer is either 1, n or the center of the largest non-taken subsequence. Checking the closest neighbour for 1 and n is straightforward, so let's focus on finding non-taken subsequence. I think the code will say the best for itself in this case:

```
largest_free = 0, largest_begin
current_free = 0, current_begin = 0
for i = 1 to n:
    if i is taken:
        if current_free > largest_free:
            largest_free = current_free
            largest_begin = current_begin
        current_begin = i + 1
        current_free = 0
    else:
        current_free += 1

if current_free > largest_free:
    largest_free = current_free
    largest_begin = current_begin
```

The overall algorithm will obviously take a linear time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out largest non-taken subsequence. That was the right direction I was looking for.

Comment: @Azmi: Many of the other answers also seek out the largest non-taken sub-sequence (aka  "gap") even if they do not mention it explicitly in any additional commentary they provide besides the code they contain -- and I suspect many do so more quickly that what is shown in this answer.

Comment: @martineau I realised that and I guess the quicker solution is to get the largest gap just based on the list of taken seats.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is about readability, not neccessarily about performance:

```
def find_max_dist(n, taken):
    # trivial cases: no or one seat taken
    if not taken:
        return 1
    elif len(taken) == 1:
        return 1 if list(taken)[0] > n//2 else n
    else: # interesting case
        taken = sorted(list(taken))
        gap_sizes = list(map(lambda x,y: y-x-1, taken, taken[1:]))
        biggest_gap_size = max(gap_sizes)

        # check if outermost seats are optimal
        if taken[0] > biggest_gap_size:
            return 1
        elif n - taken[-1] > biggest_gap_size:
            return n

        begin_of_biggest_gap = taken[gap_sizes.index(biggest_gap_size)] + 1
        return begin_of_biggest_gap + ((biggest_gap_size - 1)// 2)



print(find_max_dist(10, {}))

print(find_max_dist(10, {5}))
print(find_max_dist(10, {6}))

print(find_max_dist(11, {5}))
print(find_max_dist(11, {6}))

print(find_max_dist(10, {1, 10}))
print(find_max_dist(10, {5, 10}))
print(find_max_dist(10, {1, 5, 10}))
```

I assume that `taken` is a set. If this set is empty or contains exactly one element, the choice is clear: first seat if empty or taken seat is in second half, last seat otherwise.

If there are multiple taken seats, the biggest gap is determined. Then the code determines wether the first, the last, or the middle seat in the gap is optimal.

For your last test case, **7** should be the answer, because the second gap is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly optimal and readable to me:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip
from operator import itemgetter

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*2)

def find_max_dist(all_seats, taken_seats):
    if len(taken_seats) == len(all_seats):  # no empty seats?
        return None

    # adds a virtual seat 0 if left-most taken seat isn't 1
    taken_seats = sorted(taken_seats + ([0] if taken_seats[0] != 1 else []))
    gaps = ((p0+1, p1-1, (p1-1)-(p0+1)) for p0, p1 in pairwise(taken_seats))
    max_gap = max(gaps, key=itemgetter(2))  # interval with largest gap

    # if left-most seat of largest gap is seat 1, use it, else use gap midpoint
    return 1 if max_gap[0] == 1 else (max_gap[0] + max_gap[1]) // 2

seats = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(find_max_dist(seats, [1, 10]))    # --> 5
print(find_max_dist(seats, [5, 10]))    # --> 1
print(find_max_dist(seats, [1, 5, 10])) # --> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers and feedback. After taking all into consideration, this is my final solution.

```
def findnextseat(n,taken):
    longestgapstart = 0
    longestgaplength = 0
    gapstart = 0
    gaplength = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if len(taken) == 0:
            longestgapstart = 1
            longestgaplength = n

        if i in taken:
            if gaplength > longestgaplength:
                longestgaplength = gaplength
                longestgapstart = gapstart 
            gaplength = 0
        else:
            if i == n:
                if gaplength > longestgaplength:
                    longestgaplength = gaplength
                    longestgapstart = gapstart 
            else:
                if gaplength == 0:
                    gapstart = i
                gaplength += 1

    if longestgapstart == 1:
        return 1
    elif longestgapstart + longestgaplength == n and n not in taken:
        return n
    else:
        return longestgapstart + (longestgaplength-1)/2

print findnextseat(10,[1,10])    #5
print findnextseat(10,[5,10])    #1
print findnextseat(10,[1,5,10])  #7
print findnextseat(10,[1,3])     #10
print findnextseat(10,[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]) #3
```

Credit goes to **dubov94** for the algorithm and **Jasper** for pointing the correct solution for a test case.